# Replace for loop with lapply

Tags: r

Is it possible to replace a for loop like this:

```
library(quanteda)
library(quanteda.dictionaries)

#dummy data
df <- data.frame(text = c("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.", "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.", "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown pr

    inter took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."))

    for (j in 1:nrow(df)) {
        out <- liwcalike(df$text[j], 
                            dictionary = data_dictionary_NRC)
        dfm <- rbind(dfm, data.frame(em1 = out$trust, em2= out$anger))
    }
```

with lapply or anything else to reduce execution time?

Comment: `do.call("rbind.data.frame", c(lapply(df$text, function(txt) liwcalike(txt, dictionary = data_dictionary_NRC)[,c("trust","anger")]), stringsAsFactors=FALSE))` might work, untested. (You'll want to rename the columns next.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a list of data frames and rbind **once** outside loop and avoid the quadractic copying with `rbind` inside loop:

```
df_list <- lapply(df$text, function(txt) {
               out <- liwcalike(txt, dictionary = data_dictionary_NRC)
               return(data.frame(em1 = out$trust, em2= out$anger, origin=txt))
           }

final_df <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
```

In case of any issues with `liwcalike` call, wrap process in `tryCatch` to return `NA`-row data frame on any errors:

```
df_list <- lapply(df$text, function(txt) {
               tryCatch({
                   out <- liwcalike(txt, dictionary = data_dictionary_NRC)
                   return(data.frame(em1=out$trust, em2=out$anger, origin=txt, error=NA))
               }, error = function(e) 
                   data.frame(em1=NA, em2=NA, origin=txt, error=e)
               )
           }

final_df <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
```